# Why I am getting org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1;

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using Spring Boot 3.0.1 with Kotlin 1.7.21 and Spring Boot Starter Data JPA, and upon deleting and entity, I am getting

> org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected
> row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement
> executed: delete from article_tag where article_id=? and tag_id=?

Following is my Article Entity which have a Many To Many relationship with Tag Entity

WikiArticleDb.kt

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade= [CascadeType.ALL])
@JoinTable(name = "article_tag",
           joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "article_id", referencedColumnName = "id")],
           inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id")])
val tags: Set<WikiTagDb>? = null,
```

WikiTagDb.kt

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wiki_tag")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "WikiTagSequence", sequenceName = "wiki_tag_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
data class WikiTagDb(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "WikiTagSequence")
    override val id: Int = 0,

    val name: String,

    @Embedded
    override val meta: WorkspaceEntityMetaImpl
) : WorkspaceBasedEntity<Int>, WorkspaceEntityMeta by meta
```

WikiArticleTagMappingDb.kt

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article_tag")
data class WikiArticleTagMappingDb (
    @EmbeddedId
    val key: ArticleTagKey
) {
    constructor(articleId: Int, tagId: Int): this(ArticleTagKey(articleId, tagId))
    @Embeddable
    data class ArticleTagKey (
        @Column(name = "article_id")
        val articleId: Int,

        @Column(name = "tag_id")
        val tagId: Int
    ): Serializable
}
```

ArticleTagMappingRepository.kt

```
@Repository
interface ArticleTagMappingRepository : JpaRepository<WikiArticleTagMappingDb, WikiArticleTagMappingDb.ArticleTagKey> {
    fun findAllByKeyArticleId(articleId: Int): List<WikiArticleTagMappingDb>

    fun findAllByKeyArticleIdIn(articleIds: List<Int>): List<WikiArticleTagMappingDb>

    fun deleteAllByKeyArticleId(articleId: Int)
}
```

So when I am calling fun `deleteAllByKeyArticleId(articleId: Int)` then I am getting the above mentioned exception. Is it due to wrong entity mapping or wrong use of cascading?